# Warning in adding item to JComboBox

Tags: java

I would like to use JComboBox without any warnings and also without warning suppression as possible. I want a String to be added to a JComboBox. So, normally, to put items in a JComboBox, I use:

```
String list [] = {"Hello", "World"};
JComboBox <String> cboHello = new JComboBox <> (list);
```

This code eliminates these warnings on my compilation:

```
Note: Sample.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

But, what if I want to add an item to JComboBox? I tried these:

```
1. Object itObj = "Foo";
   cboHello.addItem(itObj);

2. cboHello.addItem("Foo");

3. cboHello.addItem <String> ("Foo");
```

The first and third one generated an error. The second one didn't eliminate warnings. I also checked Java API documentation and try this:

```
comboBox.addItem(makeObj("Item 1"));
private Object makeObj(final String item)  {
     return new Object() { public String toString() { return item; } };
}
```

But it doesn't eliminate the warnings as well. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What warnings and errors do you exactly get?

Comment: I included the warning I like to eliminate in my program. It is a warning for unchecked or unsafe operations.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
JComboBox <String> cboHello = new JComboBox <> (list);
```

You have passed String as the generic parameter for JComboBox, this tells JComboBox to accept only String in its addItem method. (Generic type is introduced to JComboBox since Java 7)

- The first one and the fourth one are essentially the same. You are trying to pass an object to a method that accepts only String. As object cannot be implicitly casted to String, you have to explicitly cast it.

  cboHello.addItem((String)itObj);
- The second one is perfectly legitimate as you passed a string to addItem which only accepts String as its parameter
- The third one is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me fix the problem!

Comment: If this post solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (click on the "tick" on the left of the post, near the arrows)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just adding strings, (2) works fine for me and doesn't give any compiler warnings.

If you're saying you'd like to add an object to your `JComboBox`, change the original declaration to:

```
JComboBox <Object> cboHello = new JComboBox<Object>(list);
```

Then your approaches (1) and (2) both work without warning or errors.

You might find it useful to read more about Jave [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), that's the source of these behaviours..